# Understanding dynamic objects ("new") in C++

Tags: c++, memory

I am trying to understand the new operator more closely. I do understand the fact that it allocated memory from the heap and returns a pointer to the memory. My question is that once I get the pointer and use it to store another pointer to another declared variable, how does the value copy or the value pointed to by happen? So for instance

i declare a variable

```
int x = 4;
```

and say

```
int* ptr = new int;
ptr = &x;
```

ptr points a chunk of memory from the heap. x is defined in a stack owning a separate chunk of memory. ptr and the address of x are the same. If I delete ptr, x is still valid as it still exists in the memory. When I say *ptr, I am looking for the value pointed to by ptr, which in this case is 4. My question is that 4, where does that reside. Does it live in two separate chunks of memory. One is represented by x and other I just got from new. How does the process happen? How does 4 get transmitted across the two chunks, or I am missing sthg? Please help.

Also when I say ptr = &x, is that a bitwise copy. In other words, do I forever loose the memory I just got access to through the heap?

Comment: Unfortunately, almost everything in your program is undefined behaviour, and most of your assumptions are wrong.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
int* ptr = new int;
ptr = &x;
```

> ptr points a chunk of memory from the heap

No, it doesn't. After the assignment, it points at the address of variable `x`, which has [automatic storage](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatic_variable). You have lost the handle to the dynamically allocated `int` initially pointed at by `ptr`, so you can no longer delete it. `4` does not get transmitted across any "chunks" of memory. When you de-reference, `ptr`, you get the variable referred to by x, which holds the value `4`.

Try this example:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{

  int x = 4;
  int* ptr = new int;
  ptr = &x;  // lose handle on dynamically allocated int: MEMORY LEAK
  std::cout << (*ptr) << "\n";
  x += 1;
  std::cout << (*ptr) << "\n";
  (*ptr) += 1;
  std::cout << x << "\n";

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can point `ptr` to any address you want, as you saw, but it doesn't mean that it's safe. Here you're doing wrong memory operation since the memory allocated on `new` is orphanned, not pointed by `ptr`. This is allowed by the language but unsafe.

So `4` is still at them same address, on the stack, it's just that it is also referenced by a `ptr` after you did `ptr=&x;`.

Comment: @user1247384 don't forget to vote up the answers that you find useful, and accept one of them

Answer (score 2):

Forget about "stack" and "heap". That's not important for what you need to understand.

Objects in C++ have one of three different storage classes: Static, dynamic, and automatic.

Automatic and static objects are those that are the value of a non-reference variable. More precisely, variables at namespace scope and static variables at block scope hold static objects, and non-static variables at block-scope hold automatic objects. The lifetime of these objects is determined by their position in the source code:

```
// file.cpp

int a;             // static, global (= "namespace scope")

void foo()
{
    static int b;  // static, block scope

    int c;         // automatic (always block scope)
}
```

By contrast, *dynamic* objects are precisely those which are created as the result of a `new` expression. Dynamic objects are never themselves variables. You can only get a hold of them via a pointer (which is itself an object), or via a reference variable (and references are never objects):

```
Foo * p = new Foo;
Foo & q = *new Foo;  // NEVER do this!
```

Dynamic objects live until you delete them explicitly, via a pointer to them:

```
delete p;    // normal
delete &q;   // works, but insane
```

In your case, `new int` creates a new, dynamic object of type `int`, and you store a pointer to this object in the variable `ptr`. However, in the very next line you overwrite the variable and lose the pointer to the dynamic integer. You have *leaked* the object, and it can no longer be recovered.